# MySQL Python query syntax mistake on INSERT when it seems to be satisfying?

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I am delevoping sample database for a Taxi service and trying to fill the PhoneCall table with some data, using Python and **mysql.connector** library. The PhoneCall table columns are:

- `idCall, int(11), PRIMARY KEY`
- `Operator_idOperator, int(11), NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY`
- `Client_idClient, int(11), NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY`
- `datetimeValue, datetime`
- `Duration, int(11)`

I declare an empty list and generate some data to fill the table:

- `query = "INSERT INTO TaxiTest.PhoneCall (idCall, Operator_idOperator, Client_idClient, datetimeValue, Duration) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"`

After that, I generate data

```
data = []
for i in range(1500):
    idCall = i + 1
    (Operator_idOperator, Client_idClient) = (20, 21) # Sample ints
    datetime_value = datetime.now()
    duration = 60
    t_tuple = (idCall, Operator_idOperator, Client_idClient, datetime_value, duration)
    data.append(t_tuple)
```

Next, I am trying to INSERT data using cursor.executemany(query, data) syntax:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cnx.autocommit = True
cursor = cnx.cursor()
try:
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    log = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Result: " + log)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err.msg)
```

So, the result is:

- `Data[0]:  (1, 46, 2521, datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 17, 22, 44, 20, 159722), 55)`
- `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
       near 'TaxiTest.PhoneCall' at line 1`

Although I have already filled about 5 tables in this database, I don't recognize any mistakes in this `INSERT` statement.

It seems that the only solution is to write all 1500 entries of data into `output.txt` file and execute that using MySQL Workbench, because **there is no error while inserting with MySQL Workbench**, but this is not appreciated.

P.S. This is my first question on StackOverflow. Waited this moment for so long to get some 'coins' for commenting and rating other questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying it, I would say it is the datetime object.

You can try this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_value = datetime.now()
formatted_date = datetime_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Inserted by using MySQL Workbench, from SQL-script file with the "INSERT ..." statement. Although, it is not possible to insert data to the database with the mysql.connector module.

Comment: Found the error in an external function, answer is totally correct

Comment: I use the MySQLdb import, so I was hoping it was the same. I am glad this solution worked for you.